# How do I use a User Defined Type in a function?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

The following trivial example doesn't work:

```
Public Type MyType
    a As Double
    b As Integer
End Type

Function Test() As Variant
    Dim x As MyType
    Test = 2
End Function
```

> Compile Error: User-defined type not defined

How do I "define" the type?

Comment: The type definition is a declaration. So it must be within the declarations **before** the first function or sub. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897495%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: @AxelRichter Yup, you're right. In my actual code I had a Function above the declaration. I didn't think it was relevant when posting the question, but as you point out it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code compiles fine in my excel 2010

anyhow it'd be of no use for exploiting a user defined type

here follows a "complete" example

```
Option Explicit

Public Type MyType
    a As Double
    b As Integer
End Type

Sub main()
    Dim x As MyType

    'initialize fields of your type
    x.a = 1.2
    x.b = 1

    MsgBox Test(x)
End Sub


Function Test(x As MyType) As Variant

    Test = x.a + x.b

End Function
```